# Is there any penalty for asking friendly civilizations for money or technology?

Tags: civilization-4

In Civilization 4 you can ask other civilizations for money or technology instead of trading. You say, "Can you spare this for a friend?" and sometimes they give it to you without expecting anything in return.

This only works if they are "pleased" or "friendly" towards you. If they are "cautious" or lower it is a demand and that lowers (-1) their opinion of you.

But it seems like, if they are pleased or friendly, you can ask it an unlimited number of times. Is that correct? Or is there some penalty (of which I am not aware)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no diplo penalty if you ask politely. While you can ask unlimited number of times, I believe there's a limit how often they can give you something.